# Transforming all keys in object into a new object

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have an object that is something similar to:

```
const obj = {
  key1: 'ajklwenrvadva',
  key2: 'bgqo420v232',
  key3: '3ou4hfv34hc'
  // ...
}
```

where each value of a key is an encrypted string that is being received.

I recently ran into a problem where I feel like there should be a method of iterating over all keys in the object, transforming the values (decrypt in this case), and insert into a new object.

The current solution I'm using is to do a loop like:

```
const newObj = {}
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) newObj[key] = decrypt(obj[key])
```

which is working perfectly fine, but for my own curiosity and sanity is there a method of doing this same thing using something like `reduce` or a similar approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be unreasonable at all, but as far as I know, there isn't anything like `map` for objects in the standard JavaScript library.

You'll see people (ab)use `reduce` for this:

```
const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    newObj[key] = decrypt(obj[key]);
    return newObj;
}, {});
```

...which can also be written (ab)using the comma operator:

```
const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => (newObj[key] = decrypt(obj[key]), newObj), {});
```

...but frankly, I've never liked it, not least because it's really easy to forget to return `newObj` from the iterator, get the error, and have to go back and add it. (To me, if the "accumulator" isn't changing, `reduce` is the wrong answer, and in the above the object reference being passed around never changes.) I just use `for-of` (as you did) or `forEach`:

```
const newObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    newObj[key] = decrypt(obj[key]);
});
```

(Or on some projects, a utility function that does it, if I find myself repeating it.)

Comment: I don't like the reduce variant because it is stateful and kinda breaks the FP style that `reduce` implies.

Comment: *(Oops: Fixed the order of the accumulator and key above. Hit refresh if it looks backward.)*

Comment: @Andrey: Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

[Lodash has something like that:](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues)

```
const newObj = _.mapValues(obj, decrypt);
```

Yes, this is not pure JS, but still may be useful.

Comment: is there any method of doing the same thing without any dependencies?

Comment: @m_callens not something that elegant, otherwise lodash wouldn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use reduce to accomplish this:

```
const obj = {hello: "World", goodbye: "Universe"};
const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((o, k) => {
  o[k] = obj[k].toUpperCase();
  return o;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2017 provides a method [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) that returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop

We could achieve it in the following way as well:

```
const obj = {
  key1: 'ajklwenrvadva',
  key2: 'bgqo420v232',
  key3: '3ou4hfv34hc'
}
let newObj = {};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => newObj[key] = decrypt(value));
```